# PHP: best way to clone a SQLite database?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm learning SQLite (with PHP), coming from a MySQL background.

I have a big project where I need to store huge csv files in a database, to enable quick searching, indexing, etc. The application always needs to use only one csv at a time, and there can potentially be thousands of csv-files, so I thought putting all data into one single database (MySQL) is not such a good idea. That's why I'm looking for a SQLite solution now.

Now my question is, how would you replicate the database structure with SQLite each time?

Do I need an empty 'dummy' database file, that I copy each time a new csv-file is uploaded?

Or would a script that generates the database be better?

And also, how would I deal with an eventual change in the database schema (in a newer version of the software) ? All existing database files would have to be changed then.

Comment: Create an empty SQLite database that you never populate, then when you want to clone it, just copy it using file operations. I am not sure that you'll get a speed increase using SQLite though - if you normalise your CSV data into MySQL tables properly, it should be fine.

Comment: How many tables you expect?

Comment: Hmm @ _"all existing database files"_. This sounds like a problem waiting to happen - again, I'd recommend putting it all in the one MySQL database. (Though I can only guess - there's not enough info here to be certain of that.)